# Design advice for SQL cancer specimen database

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, medical

I’m a pathologist designing a database containing surgical specimen data collected from cancer patients at my hospital.  Currently it looks something like this in MySQL:

```
Specimen_id    Variable       Value
1            Tumor_stage       pT3
1            Node_stage        pN2
1           Other_findings    diverticulitis
2            Tumor stage       pT1
2            Node_stage        pN1
2           Other_findings    adenomas
2           Other_findings    dysplasia
2           Other_findings    Crohns_disease
```

I want to ensure that specimens can only have a single entry for some variables, (i.e. specimens can only have a single Tumor_stage and Node_stage), but can have multiple entries for other variables—like “Other_findings”.  Are there some sort of contraints I could add to the table to achive this?

Alternatively, I could design the table like this:

```
Specimen_id  Tumor_stage   Node_stage        Other_findings
1                 pT3         pN2                 ?
2                 pT1         pN1                 ?
```

But then I wasn’t sure how to associate an arbitrarily long list of values for the “Other_findings” variables to specimen.

Sorry if this is super simple. I’m sort of a novice at this stuff.  Thanks

Comment: MySQL has poor support for constraints, so pretty much your only option is using triggers.

Comment: Or building the logic into the INSERT itself - or have a separate table for other findings

Comment: What should happen in the event that someone tries to add another instance of a restricted variable?

Comment: @Gordon is right about the poor support, but I wonder if this works? `CREATE VIEW` filtered to just those `Variable`s that should have a single value. Declare a key for that view.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!  I'll check out these options.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably design two tables like this:

```
create table specimens as (
    specimen_id int primary key,
    Tumor_stage varchar(255),
    Node_stage varchar(255)
);

create table specimens_findings as (
    specimen_findings_id int auto_increment primary key,
    Specimen_id int,
    other_finding varchar(255)
    foreign key (specimen_id) references specimens (specimen_id)
);
```

You may want the `tumor_stage`, `node_stage`, and `other_finding` fields to actually have foreign key relationships to appropriate reference tables, so the values are limited to a specific group.  You could also implement `enum`s for the same purpose.